# Get all related instances from has_many through relationship of a polymorphic class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphism, has-many-through

I'm trying to create way for Users to Like content in my project. To do this I set up a polymorphic relationship as follows

Likes table

```
table "likes", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "likeable_id"
  t.string   "likeable_type"
  t.integer  "user_id",       null: false
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :newsletters, through: :likes, source: :likeable, source_type: "newsletter"
  has_many :gift_cards, through: :likes, source: :likeable, source_type: "gift_card"
  has_many :stories, through: :likes, source: :likeable, source_type: "story"
end

class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :likeable, polymorphic: true
end

class Newsletter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :like, as: :likeable, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :user, through: :like, source: :likeable
end

class GiftCard < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes, as: :likeable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :likes, source: :likeable
end

class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes, as: :likeable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :likes, source: :likeable
end
```

tldr: a User has many Likes and many Newsletters, GiftCards, and Stories through those Likes.

My question, with this structure, whats the best way to get everything a User has liked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up figuring it out. Just had some small syntactical errors

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :newsletters, through: :likes, source: :likeable, source_type: "Newsletter"
  has_many :gift_cards, through: :likes, source: :likeable, source_type: "GiftCard"
  has_many :stories, through: :likes, source: :likeable, source_type: "Story"
end

class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :likeable, polymorphic: true
end

class Newsletter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :like, as: :likeable, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :user, through: :like
end

class GiftCard < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes, as: :likeable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :likes
end

class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes, as: :likeable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :likes
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For me this is extremely hard to follow for a domain with is in reality is quite straightforwards. Perhaps you have a bigger reason to implement it is this way but here's my suggestion for the `User` `Like` and `GiftCard` models (which may or may not help!).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :liked_giftcards, through: :likes, source: :giftcard
end

class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :giftcard
end

class GiftCard < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
end

class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...same as GiftCard
end
```

Personally I would find this easier to follow. It provides easy access to everything a user has liked through `user.likes` and allows you to look at each category individually through `user.liked_giftcards` etc.

Comment: Ended up figuring this out myself but thanks for helping!

Comment: Great! Please add your answer!